# Virtual host in Windows 10 with xampp and laravel

Tags: laravel, windows, xampp, virtualhost

I want to make virtual host "mail.test" but i get this error :

> **The requested URL could not be retrieved**
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://mail.test/
>
> Unable to forward this request at this time.
>
> This request could not be forwarded to the origin server or to any parent caches.
>
> Some possible problems are:
>
> An Internet connection needed to access this domains origin servers may be down.
> All configured parent caches may be currently unreachable.
> The administrator may not allow this cache to make direct connections to origin servers.

---

these are my configurations :

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mail.test
```

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/mail/public"
    ServerName mail.test
    ServerAlias mail.test
</VirtualHost>
```

In chrome browser I go to "http://mail.test/"

Comment: Try putting a [<directory>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) entry  in your settings. Also make sure you restart apache after configuration changes and verify your custom configuration gets loaded and there are no errors

Comment: Try asking on Webmasters or SuperUser sites

Comment: I did a fresh installation of Xampp 8.1.17 in my computer, used the same configuration you've posted here, and it worked! By the way: as this is the first virtual host configured in the installation (default vhost), it will also answer requests to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my Laptop and everything goes OK!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After editing virtual host files and configuration it is a must to restart your Xampp to get the new changes

Answer (score 0):

You should try Laragon for these type of things, it does really easy with lots of features.